# Change IronPython version in Edge.js?

Tags: node.js, ironpython, edgejs

I am testing Edge.JS since I need to run Python functions from Node.js. The problem is that Edge seems to want another version of IronPython:

`Could not load file or assembly 'IronPython, Version=2.7.0.40, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7f709c5b713576e1' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

I have `2.7.6.3` installed, should I downgrade? Or is there a way to set the version in edge?

Comment: This looks really like problem that is realated to `edge`. Is you IronPython env. working? For example `ipy.exe`?

Comment: IronPython is working, I got a message from the main Edge contributor, it seems the IronPython version is hard coded, and I ll need to recompile it after making the change.

Comment: Do you mean hard coded in Edge? Can we help you with something?

Comment: @BendEg: Yes, hardcoded in Edge. Well, I ll have to find how to compile Edge, or recompile IronPython so it output another version, whichever is easier and future proof. So yes, I ll probably need help, but they would warrant another question.

Comment: @DrakanSAN in this case it sounds more reasonable, to fix it in Edge, because "faking" a version number shouldn't be the best solution.

Comment: @BendEg I agree, but it will be easier to find how to compile IronPython than Edge.

Comment: @Yes, that might be easer. If you need any help, join our gitter channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem come from Edge, where the version number is hardcoded.